# ActionBarDrawerToggle is obsolete

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am using xamarin forms package that contains the support package v4.
I want to do a simple side menu with this code:

```
menuDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.Menu);
menu = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.LeftDrawer);

menuItems.Add("First item");
menuItems.Add("Second item");

menuDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, menuDrawerLayout, Resource.Drawable.navigationbarmenu, Resource.String.open_menu, Resource.String.close_menu);

menuDrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(menuDrawerToggle);
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);

menuAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, menuItems);
menu.Adapter = menuAdapter;
```

Whenever ActionBarDrawerToggle is reminded there is a green underline that tells this:

> ActionBarDrawerToggle is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android platform'

I have been searching the internet and especially stack overflow for hours and still didn`t find a working solution.

Comment: Can't you use the v7 support library instead?

Comment: I have tried but than I dont know how to put an image in the new ActionBarDrawerToggle, it tells me that I cant convert int to Android.Support.V7.widget.toolbar @Michael

Comment: `ActionBarDrawerToggle` was deprecated in v4 and thus you should use v7 instead. Please update your question with any faliures you occur such as the conversion issuue. You are most likely still using a v4 reference to where it expects the v4 type instead of the v7 type. Remove any trace of v4